# ¿Cómo ocultar un modal cuando aparece otro modal?

Tags: reactjs

Tengo un modal en el cual hay un boton que abre otro modal, mi problema es que cuando doy click en el boton el modal que se abre queda detras del modal activo.

este modal es el que se abre con un componente donde hay un formulario y es donde se encuentra el boton ya mencionado.

```
<Modal id="modal2"  title="Edit Configuracion" cancel={true} >
  <div>
     {this.state.toEdit && <EditConf item={this.state.toEdit}/>}
  </div>
</Modal>
```

El siguiente boton es donde se abre el modal:

```
<a data-target="modal" className="btn-floating modal-trigger" href="#modal"><i className="material-icons">search</i></a>
```

donse se abre el siguiente modal:

```
<Modal id="modal" className="modal" title="Busqueda de cliente" close={true}>
   <div >
      <SearchClient onCopy={this.onCopy.bind(this)}/>
   </div>
</Modal>
```

No se como resolverlo ya que intente jugar con "z-index" y no funciona.
Saludos.

Comment: ¿por qué no te funciona ajustando el z-index? esa debería ser la manera de arreglarlo ¿acaso no cambia el z-index después de revisarlo en el explorador?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

si lo que quieres es ocultar un modal cuando te aparece otro u ocultar y mostrar un modal dependiendo de una acción determinada, en mi opinión personal lo más viable es trabajar con el state de React, el modal sin importar a que librería pertenece, posee una propiedad que es la que dice si se muestra o no se muestra, si está visible o no, etc. Tan solo tienes que crear un espacio en el state para almacenar el valor que luego vas a utilizar para mostrar o no tu modal, este valor lo puedes ir cambiando mediante funciones llamadas con eventos onClick u otro evento según la necesidad del momento.  No tengo a mano tu código o al menos no tanto como para poder darte una solución específica para tu problema. Pero a continuación te paso el código de un componente de un proyecto en el que me encuentro trabajando ahora, funciona perfectamente y espero que te sea de ayuda como ejemplo. Cualquier duda no dudes en comentar.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Modal } from 'antd';

import UpdateUserForm from './UpdateUserForm';

class UpdateUserModal extends Component {
  state = { visible: false }

  showModal = () => {
    this.setState({
      visible: true,
    });
  }

  handleOk = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      visible: false,
    });
  }

  handleCancel = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      visible: false,
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <a type="primary" onClick={this.showModal}>
          edit
        </a>
        <Modal
          title="Basic Modal"
          visible={this.state.visible}
          onOk={this.handleOk}
          onCancel={this.handleCancel}
          footer={null}
        >
          <UpdateUserForm item={this.props.item} findAndSetDates={this.props.findAndSetDates} />
        </Modal>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default UpdateUserModal;
```